# Nested string literals in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, templates, template-literals

I'm trying to create a function to take in 2 params and return a template string. If this occurs: `window.location.href.endsWith('BRONCHOSCOPY')`, I'd like to run a function which generates the code below (but need the procedure1 number to change according to a second argument to pull in a value from an array).

```
if (window.location.href.endsWith('BRONCHOSCOPY')) {
    extraInfo.innerHTML = `<b>${thoracics.procedures.procedure1.extraInfo}</b>`;
    procedure.innerHTML = `<b>${thoracics.procedures.procedure1.name}<b>`;
    firstColumn.innerHTML = `${thoracics.procedures.procedure1.textFirstColumn}`;
    secondColumn.innerHTML = `${thoracics.procedures.procedure1.textSecondColumn}`;
    icon.innerHTML = `<img src="${thoracics.src}" width="40" height="40" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="${thoracics.alt}' loading="lazy"></img>`; 
}
```

I have a function like this:

```
 function procedureInfo(arg, x) {
    return `extraInfo.innerHTML = <b>${${arg}.procedures.procedure.extraInfo}</b>
    procedure.innerHTML = <b>${${arg}.procedures.procedure${x}.name}<b>
    firstColumn.innerHTML = ${${arg}.procedures.procedure${x}.textFirstColumn}
    secondColumn.innerHTML = ${${arg}.procedures.procedure${x}.textSecondColumn};
    icon.innerHTML = <img src="${${arg}.src}" width="40" height="40" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="${${arg}.alt}' loading="lazy"></img>`
  }
```

JS doesn't like the syntax, like a nested array, and I'm sure there's an easier way to do this.

Comment: You can't return a template string, it's parsed to a string in place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please keep in mind that setting `innerHTML` with dynamic content is dangerous since it creates an [XSS vulnerability](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/xss/) in your application.

With that in mind, why not return a function like this?

```js
function procedureInfo(arg, x) {
  return () => {
    const procedure = arg.procedures[`procedure${x}`];

    extraInfo.innerHTML = `<b>${procedure.extraInfo}</b>`;
    procedure.innerHTML = `<b>${procedure.name}<b>`;
    firstColumn.innerHTML = procedure.textFirstColumn;
    secondColumn.innerHTML = procedure.textSecondColumn;
    icon.innerHTML = `<img src="${arg.src}" width="40" height="40" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="${arg.alt}" loading="lazy" />`;
  };
}

const code = procedureInfo(thoracics, 1);

// later...
// instead of eval(code);
code();
```

You might also consider making `thoracics.procedures` an array instead of object with numbered properties in order to simplify your logic for accessing the appropriate nested properties.